# Stepper Motor Calculations

Tags: microcontroller, power, stepper-motor, beaglebone-black

I am currently struggling to determine some parameters of a stepper motor I am using. I am trying to calculate the number of pulses per second I can deliver to the motor reliably. This is relatively new topic for me and am having trouble understanding where this value is determined.

The data sheet for the Motor is here:
http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/157a/0900766b8157a734.pdf

If this value is determined by what drives the motor, the driver is here:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf

The MicroController I am using is the BeagleBone Black.

EDIT:
Perhaps a better way of asking my question... I already know that the step angle is 0.9, therefore the steps per revolution (SPR) is 400, thus 400 pulses per revolution. However, my true question is how do I determine the number of pulses I can deliver to the motor per second?

Comment: You can deliver any number of pulses you want. The question is, will the motor actually step from them? That depends on physics as much as electronics; specifically the inertia of the load on the motor. There are things you can do to improve motor response, including ramp the speed up and down slowly (control the acceleration rate) and raise the voltage as the pulses shorten, to maintain the current (= torque) despite rising inductive impedance. It's a complex subject, more like a book than an answer. Until you know enough to write that book, your best bet is to experiment with what you have.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you for your answer. So am I correct I could deliver what ever number of pulses my MicroController could output? but it depends on many factors whether the motor will actually handle them?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Also, would it be reasonable for me to assume 2x revolutions per second (A very small load is applied)? or is that too vague of a question?

Comment: 2 revs/second is probably within reach with a simple basic driver. 5 or 10 would be another matter.